# The deferred EL expression is not allowed, since deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral is false

Tags: jsf, weblogic11g

I was getting the following error when I execute JSF page.

> The deferred EL expression is not allowed since `deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral` is false.

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{login.username}"/>
```

Thus I had changed file extension from login.jsp to login.xhtml

This file and many other files contains lots of Java code inside `<% ..%>`, so what is the best approach in keeping the Java code intact and I would like my legacy application get deployed to Weblogic 11g (10.1.3.6), Changing all JSP scriplets is quite a herculean task and wouldn't be doing this as this is a legacy application.

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>prod</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.app.Login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DBervice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.app.common.DBService</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LAPService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.app.LAPService</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DBervice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dbservice</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LAPService</servlet-name>
```

Comment: @BalusC I have included web.xml where FacesServlet is defined.

Comment: @BalusC You mean faces-config.xml?

Comment: @BalusC Sorry, URL is `http://localhost:7001/apps/login`

Comment: @BalusC Login Servlet gets authentication details and forwards response to jsf page. `response.sendRedirect("faces/my_list.jsp");` As I mentioned earlier, this is a legacy application and wouldn't be spending time on modifying code.

Comment: @BalusC My other option would be to use JSF1.1 or JSF 1.2 libraries in Weblogic server. Thus I wouldn't need to change any legacy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should simply set:

```
<%@ page deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral="true" %>
```

in all of your JSP pages. It [should work](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/jviewtgo/v8r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ilog.jviews.tgo.doc%2FContent%2FVisualization%2FDocumentation%2FJViews%2FJViews_TGO%2F_pubskel%2Fps_usrwebjtgo624.html) with Weblogic 10.3. You can probably write some sort of `sed` call to do it in every JSP.